# How do i conditionally format rows in property grid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a property grid, working few years on wpf has rusted my winforms knowledge.

I want to make property name text bold in some cases, I want to use a bool return value from a method, and decide if property name is to be displayed as bold.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, what property what event!?

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day...

Really, this is going way back. I don't remember that there was a way to control the property name appearance directly. You could make sure your property descriptors had categories and those categories would be bold.

Also (and I don't think this is still true in "later" versions of Windows), you could return true from your property descriptor's `ShouldSerializeValue` method...and it would cause the PropertyGrid to display the property *value* in bold.

Also seems like you could identify *one* of your properties as the object's default property (in the object's type descriptor). Seems like there were differing behaviors depending on the version of Windows...after XP, I think this would float the property to the top...but maybe XP and before it would make the property name bold...but I could be misremembering. I've slept more than once since then.

With the property grid, I seem to remember running into the argument that doing any more formatting might interfere with all the complex layout the grid was already doing on the object's behalf. Back then, I was using the property grid to format hierarchical objects...and I remember being impressed with it's capabilities despite it's relative lack of formatting control.

Of course, after spending time in WPF, you can't help but feel like you can affect anything and everything, yes?

Comment: yea wpf gives u a <false> feeling of being tony stark